# Monoidal structure on presheaves

Tags: higher-category-theory, modules, monoidal-categories

I am confused about the following monoidal structure, which gives a symmetric monoidal structure on R-modules (that I think is not Cartesian), even if R is not commutative.

Let $C$ be a small category. Then there is a diagonal functor $\Delta: C \rightarrow C \times C$. Let $Psh(C)= Fun(C^{op}, Spaces) $ denote presheaves over $C$. Then
$$
Psh(C\times C) \cong Psh(C)\otimes_L Psh(C)
$$
where $\otimes_L$ is the Lurie tensor product on presentable categories $PrL$
(see [Symmetric monoidal structures on the functor taking presheaves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445166/symmetric-monoidal-structures-on-the-functor-taking-presheaves) for discussion of this statement). By pulling back along the diagonal functor, we get a colimit-preserving functor
$$
\Delta^*: Psh(C) \otimes_L Psh(C) \cong Psh(C\times C) \rightarrow Psh(C)
$$
which can be viewed as a tensor product on $Psh(C)$, which becomes a monoid in $PrL$.

As a variant, if we work with spectra $Sp$ instead of $Spaces$, $Fun(C^{op}, Sp)$ is one definition of $C$-modules. So there seems to be a monoidal structure on $C$-modules, and if $C = BR$, then this seems to be usual tensor product on $R$-modules. however, I thought that such a tensor product only exists if $R$ is commutative.
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+product+of+modules

Question: Does this mean that there is a symmetric monoidal structure on $R$-modules, even if $R$ is *not* commutative?

Remark: There is another ``Cartesian" monoidal structure on $Psh(C)$ induced by point-wise post-composing with $Spaces \times Spaces \rightarrow Spaces$ and I think these two monoidal structures are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the diagonal functor $\mathcal C\to\mathcal C\otimes\mathcal C$ is not additive for a small pre-additive $\infty$-category $\mathcal C$ (and you want to take $\mathcal C=BR$), to make the following work:

$$\DeclareMathOperator\Fun{Fun}\DeclareMathOperator\add{add}\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}\Fun^{\add}(\mathcal C,\Sp)\otimes^L\Fun^{\add}(\mathcal C,\Sp)=\Fun^{\add}(\mathcal C\otimes\mathcal C,\Sp)\to\Fun^{\add}(\mathcal C,\Sp)$$

where the second arrow is given by pulling back along the expected additive functor $\Delta\colon\mathcal C\to\mathcal C\otimes\mathcal C$. When $\mathcal C=BR$, functors $\Delta$ (along with co-unit, co-associativity and co-commutativity) roughly correspond to co-commutative co-ring structures on $R$, and in particular, if $R$ is a Hopf algebra (e.g. a spherical group ring), you do have this symmetric monoidal structure on $D(R)$.

However, let me mention that this symmetric monoidal structure is *of a very different nature* from the relative tensor product when $R$ is a commutative ring: the forgetful functor $D(R)\to\Sp$ is symmetric monoidal. Such a symmetric monoidal structure usually comes from representation theory (e.g. tensor product of representations are given by the tensor product of underlying modules instead of any sort of relative tensor product).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Indeed, I forgot that $R-mod \cong Fun^{Ab-enriched}(BR, Sp)$ and not $Fun(BR, Sp)$. However, I think my question remains. There seems to be at least two different monoidal structures on presheaves $Fun(C^{op}, Spaces)$ or $Fun(C^{op}, Sp)$ for any category $C$ (but these presheaves are not Ab-enriched), and I am a bit confused about what they are.

Comment: @user39598 The Cartesian monoidal structure on presheaf categories is probably the same as the one out of diagonal. I am not sure about a reference, but it seems to be a kind of categorified Eilenberg Swindle: given a topological group $G$, the group structure on the fundamental group is either given by co-multiplication $S^1\to S^1\vee S^1$, or the multiplication $G\times G\to G$, and the two structures are the same by Eilenberg swindle.